# Export MySQL Data to MS Excel is working well in local but not on server

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel

```
<title>Orders Export</title>

<body>


<?php 
 header('Content-Type: application/xls');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls');

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','suresafe_admin','iwant$100','suresafe_suresafety');



    $query = "select * from `orders_approval` where `approve`='1' and `company_name`='GAVL-F111'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$output = '';
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
  $output .= '?>
   <table class="table" bordered="1">  
                    <tr>  
                         <th>order_no</th>  
                         <th>order_date</th>  
                         <th>order_name</th> 
                         <th>total_amount</th> 

                    </tr><?php
  ';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $output .= '
    <tr>  
                         <td>'.$row["order_no"].'</td>  
                         <td>'.$row["order_date"].'</td>  
                         <td>'.$row["order_name"].'</td>  
                         <td>'.$row["total_amount"].'</td>  

                    </tr>
   ';
  }
  $output .= '</table>';


 }?>


</body>
</html>
```

The code is simple. Working well in local. But when I use this in my website on server. It shows only table with data. It don't export that data in Excel.

```
order_no    order_date  order_name  total_amount
100000705   2017-05-07  MR. PRADEEP Y   113500
100000708   2017-05-11  MR. A SRINIVASA RAO     5448
100000725   2017-05-30  MR. A SRINIVASA RAO     77180
```

Here is the result I can see when I click on export link.

In local server, it is easily exported.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: hello nikita. Welcome. First, you should post where you think code fails, what are your problems, what have you tried etc. With this question, little help can be done.

Comment: i have updated my question again.

Comment: If the provided answer is helpful, please mark it accepted with the green check mark ✅. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you had [configured your server properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1255289), you would be seeing warnings. You cannot send a header after data has already been output. In addition, the data you're sending is not `application/xls` (which is not a valid MIME type) it's `text/html`. You're also outputting "?>" and "<?php" into your HTML, which will not work too well.

However, I would suggest going with CSV for the data you're outputting:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "suresafe_admin", "iwant$100", "suresafe_suresafety");
$query = "SELECT order_no, order_date, order_name, total_amount from orders_approval WHERE approve = 1 AND company_name = 'GAVL-F111'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$output = "";
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $output .= "order_no,order_date,order_name,total_amount\n";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output .= "$row[order_no],$row[order_date],$row[order_name],$row[total_amount]\n";
    }
}
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.csv");
echo $output;
```